# Can I put two Mac OSX installers on the same USB memory stick?

Tags: macos, installation

I copied Snow Leopard [from a DVD onto USB stick](http://www.maciverse.com/install-os-x-snow-leopard-from-usb-flash-drive.html) to install on a Mac with no DVD, and now I'm keen to upgrade to Lion, but I want to keep a copy of that after buying through the AppStore.

What do I actually get through the AppStore, is it a simply DMG? And As far as putting this on the same USB stick as the 10.6 installer, can I just copy it across or will I need to reformat with a separate partition for each installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can do that, if you create 2 separate partitions for the 2 installers.

The Lion installer from the Mac App Store is an .app, that contains a .dmg that you need. You can copy the .app to the USB, but you won't be able to boot from that. What you probably want to do is to create a bootable USB from the dmg as shown [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/).

You may be able to repartition the USB without losing the existing SL installation data, so that at the end you have 2 bootable partitions on the USB and so that can boot from either the SL or Lion install images. See [this post at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/256299/how-can-i-add-a-new-partition-to-my-hd-without-reformatting) about when this could be possible.

Whatever you decide to do, I would strongly recommend that you back up the Lion installation .app file and the existing SL install partition that is currently on the USB.

Edit: obviously you want to make sure that you have enough space on the USB stick. 16GB should be enough, given that 8GB is enough for each partition.